# How to set Input tags to enable in a specific table row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create dynamic table that can be set to editable and not, I'm using `<input>` tags because I'm submitting the data via form to php.

Here is a screen shot of the table.

[image]

So what I want to happen is if I click the row's edit field button the `<input>` tags on that row would be set to editable.

I set `<input type="text" readonly>`.

Comment: Try this   $("id for input ").prop("readonly", false);

Comment: Hello @HemaNandagopal such a coincidence that both of us working on same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.prop()` function :

```
$('.enableEdit').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('readonly', false);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Where `.enableEdit` is the class of your edit button.

Comment: Well you can change the contents of the `.find()` function like this : `.find('input,select')`

Comment: it does'nt work for the select, I've also tried `.find('select').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: I got it the first time, it just won't work for the `<select>` tag

Comment: `find('select').prop('disabled', false)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you show me your HTML so I can try to debug this?

Comment: No worries I've found a way how to fix this, great help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
       $("#txt").prop("readonly", false);
     
    });
});
</script>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
input:-moz-read-only { /* For Firefox */
    background-color: yellow;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id ="txt" readonly /></td>
    <td><button id="edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this,Hope this resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>Heading </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 $('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 
 $('.edit').click(function(){
 
  var fullid = this.id.split('_');
  var id = fullid['1']
  
  $('#row_'+id+ '  input').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#row_'+id+ '  select').removeAttr('disabled');  
  
 });
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">

 <div id="row_1">
  <input  type="text" value='2' name="edit[userid]"  />
  <select>
   <option>Supplier</option>
  </select>
  
  <select>
   <option>Test Supplier</option>
  </select>
  
  <button type="button" id="edit_1"  class="edit" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</button>
 </div>
 
 <div id="row_2">
  <input  type="text" value='2' name="edit[userid]"  />
  <select>
   <option>Supplier</option>
  </select>
  
  <select>
   <option>Test Supplier</option>
  </select>
  
  <button type="button" id="edit_2"  class="edit" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</button>
 </div>
 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```